# Combining two dataFrames in which the order of entries don't match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes called df and df2 ,a small example of both are shown below. I want to join the two into a combined dataframe by matching the entries of the dataFrame by the 'formula' column df2 with the 'filename' column of df1 since the order of entries in the 2 dataFrames are not the same. An example of the final ideal dataframe is also provided below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'filename': ['Fe12Co4BN.cif', 'Fe16N2.cif', 'Fe15CoBN.cif'],
               'jml_bp_mult_atom_rad': [170.11, 154.73, 172.43],
               'jml_hfus_add_bp': [45.13, 41.90, 47.23]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'formula': ['Fe12Co4BN','Fe15CoBN','Fe16N2'],
                'nsites': [8, 8, 8],
                'number': [139, 139, 140]})
```

Combined dataFrame should look like this:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'formula': ['Fe12Co4BN','Fe15CoBN','Fe16N2'],
                'jml_bp_mult_atom_rad': [170.11, 172.43, 154.73],
                'jml_hfus_add_bp': [45.13, 47.23, 41.90],
                'nsites': [8, 8, 8],
                'number': [139, 139, 140]})
```

The order of of the columns matters to me, so the 'formula' column should be first followed by the columns in df1 and then df2.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using `merge()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a temporary column in first dataframe `df` and use merge:

```py
out = df2.merge(
    df.assign(formula=df["filename"].str.split(".").str[0]), on="formula"
).drop(columns="filename")

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
     formula  nsites  number  jml_bp_mult_atom_rad  jml_hfus_add_bp
0  Fe12Co4BN       8     139                170.11            45.13
1   Fe15CoBN       8     139                172.43            47.23
2     Fe16N2       8     140                154.73            41.90
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `merge` with a custom key on left side:

```
out = df.merge(df2, left_on='filename', right_on=df2['formula'] + '.cif').drop(columns='filename')
print(out)

# Output
   jml_bp_mult_atom_rad  jml_hfus_add_bp    formula  nsites  number
0                170.11            45.13  Fe12Co4BN       8     139
1                154.73            41.90     Fe16N2       8     140
2                172.43            47.23   Fe15CoBN       8     139
```